# How do you determine which of Material colors to use for what

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, material-design

I'm learning Android (Compose) development and have recently faced an issue where I don't understand theming properly. My problem is that I have no idea which color name(primary, onPrimary, background etc) to use whenever I need a color. Suppose I want to write a text field - which color do I use there as a text color? I tried searching info, but it's either too complex or I still don't get it. Please point me out to some learning material about this topic. I just want to get more confident styling my application and choosing right color names.

Answer (score 2):

Material Design is a design system which has 3 styles (in compose).

1. Colors
2. Typography
3. Shapes

When you use M3 (Material 3) in your compose application the theme will be accessible in your composable using CompositionLocal technique and all the material views like Text, Button, etc... reads its proper color and shape from the theme (if you're curious about the color used in a textfield, it is specified in the Material Design guidelines).

There are tokens in this design system which help us to reuse an style (color, typography or shape), such as primary, onPrimary, primaryContainer, Secondary, OnSecondary, SecondaryContainer and so on.

These are some of them:

1. **Primary**

Primary roles are used for key components across the UI, such as the FAB, prominent buttons, active states, as well as the tint of elevated surfaces.

- **Primary** base color
- **On-primary** is applied to content (icons, text, etc.) that sits on top of primary
- **Primary container** is applied to elements needing less emphasis than primary
- **On-primary container** is applied to content (icons, text, etc.) that sits on top of primary container

2. **Secondary**

Secondary roles are used for less prominent components in the UI, such as filter chips, while expanding the opportunity for color expression.

3. **Tertiary**

Tertiary roles are used for contrasting accents that can be used to balance primary and secondary colors or bring heightened attention to an element, such as an input field.

let me give an example, you can apply primary color on a button like "Login" which is the most important action in a login screen and apply secondary color for the "Register" button in the same screen but what color for the text of these buttons can we use? the *onPrimary* and *onSecondary*.

for more information you can read https://m3.material.io.

Answer (score 0):

Check out [Theming in Compose with Material 3](https://developer.android.com/codelabs/jetpack-compose-theming) codelab.
[Here](https://m3.material.io/components) you can find specs on different components including color, size etc. Hope this helps.